# 'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'get_absolute_url'

Tags: python, django, view

On our Q/A site commenting has suddenly stopped working. When trying to post a comment I get the follwing error:

```
Traceback:
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/app/src/inteokej/installed_apps/QAManager/views/threads.py" in my_post_comment
  98.         return redirect(comment.get_absolute_url())

Exception Type: AttributeError at /comments/post/
Exception Value: 'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'get_absolute_url'
```

[Read the full Traceback](http://jpst.it/CnRz)

Here's the code for commenting in the view:

```
def my_post_comment(request,next=None,using=None):
    (model, target)=get_comment_target(request)
    user=request.user
    if not user.has_perm(PERM_APP+'can_comment'):
        if model==Question and target.user==request.user:
            if not user.has_perm(PERM_APP+"can_comment_own_question"):
                raise Exception('You cannot comment your own question')
        elif model==Answer and (target.user==request.user or target.question.user==request.user):
            if not user.has_perm(PERM_APP+"can_comment_own_answer"):
                raise Exception('You cannot comment your own answer')
        else:
            raise Exception('You cannot comment')

    comment=post_comment_from_form(request, model, target, next=None,using=None)
    #raise Exception(comment)

    if request.is_ajax():
        data=simplejson.dumps({'result':render_to_string('comments/list.html',{'comment_list':[comment]},context_instance=RequestContext(request))})
        return HttpResponse(data,mimetype='application/json')
    else:
        #return render_to_response('comments/list.html',{'comment_list':[comment]},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        return redirect(comment.get_absolute_url())
```

What does this mean? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error is on this line:

```
return redirect(comment.get_absolute_url())
```

It is telling you that comment is an `HttpResponse`, not a `Comment` instance. Therefore it doesn't have a `get_absolute_url()` method.

Since comment is set on this line:

```
comment=post_comment_from_form(request, model, target, next=None,using=None)
```

You need to look at your `post_comment_from_form` method. If you are going to use the method in this view, it needs to return the `comment`, not an `HttpResponse`.